# Issues with nginx reverse proxy to an app server running nginx+django

Tags: python, ajax, django, nginx, proxy

I have an app running on Server A. I have a Server B that I want to use as a reverse proxy for accessing the app on Server A. Server A is running nginx 1.4.5 and Django (Python 2.7.6 with fastcgi), Server B is running nginx 1.4.5 as well. I also want to add on SSL that way.

The proxy is kinda working. The issue is that requests don't see to get passed along correctly. When going to https://servera.org/ I only get a 404 error instead of the log-in page I'm expecting.

This is the error message I am seeing in the browser (it's an error message, so I know the request is reaching Server A):

```
Page not found (404)
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://nova.iguw.tuwien.ac.at/index.html
Using the URLconf defined in TUBadges.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:
1. ^admin/doc/
2. ^admin/
3. ^$
4. ^badges/?$
5. ^badges/(?P<uid>\d+)/?$
6. ^presets/$
7. ^svg$
8. ^bgsvg$
9.
```

This is my config for the reverse proxy:

```
upstream server_a {
    server servera.org:8080 fail_timeout=0;
}

server {
    listen              443 ssl;
    listen          80;
    server_name         subdomain1.serverb.org;
    server_name     subdomain2.serverb.org;
    keepalive_timeout   70;

    ssl_certificate     /etc/certificates/server_b.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/certificates/server_b.key; 

    error_log           /var/log/nginx/aurora.ssl.error.log error;
    access_log          off;

    client_max_body_size 50M;

    location ~ ^/(.+)$ {
        proxy_intercept_errors  off;
        proxy_buffering     off;

        proxy_connect_timeout 5;
        proxy_send_timeout    5;
        proxy_read_timeout    5;

        proxy_set_header    Host                $host;
        proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-By      $server_addr:$server_port;
        proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-Fo      $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-Proto   $scheme;
        proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-For     $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;

        access_log          off;
        error_log           /var/log/nginx/tubadges.error.log debug;

        proxy_pass          http://server_a;
        proxy_redirect      off;
    }
}
```

And that is the config I'm using on Server A to run the app:

```
server {
    listen                  8080; ## listen for ipv4
    server_name             localhost;
    server_name             servera.org;
    client_max_body_size    5M;
    error_log               /var/log/nginx/app1.error.log;
    access_log              /var/log/nginx/app1.access.log;

    location /static {
        root /srv/django/projects/app1;
    }
    location /media {
        root /srv/django/projects/app1;
    }
    location / {
        # host and port to fastcgi server
        fastcgi_pass unix:/srv/django/run/app1.socket;

        fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param REQUEST_METHOD $request_method;
        fastcgi_param QUERY_STRING $query_string;
        fastcgi_param CONTENT_TYPE $content_type;
        fastcgi_param CONTENT_LENGTH $content_length;
        fastcgi_param SERVER_ADDR $server_addr;
        fastcgi_param SERVER_PORT $server_port;
        fastcgi_param SERVER_NAME $server_name;
        fastcgi_param SERVER_PROTOCOL $server_protocol;
        fastcgi_param REMOTE_ADDR $remote_addr;
        fastcgi_pass_header Authorization;
        fastcgi_intercept_errors off;
    }
}
```

I'm assuming that it's got something to do with my Django App config or the config on Server A.

Can you spot an error? Do you need more information?
Is there, maybe, an answer on here that I have just missed?

Thanks in advance!

P.S.: This is my first time asking a question on StackOverflow, so if there's a way that I can improve my question to get better answers, and you see something that really bugs, please don't hesitate to point out to me how I can improve this question. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, it looks like Nginx is correctly passing the request through - the error page comes from Django (so the request is being serviced by Apache) and it states that the url:

http://nova.iguw.tuwien.ac.at/index.html

cannot be resolved to any of the urls defined in `TUBadges.urls`

You need to hit a url such as http://nova.iguw.tuwien.ac.at/admin/login or something like that.

Comment: I go through all the trouble of stripping out the actual URIs from the config, and forget them in the error message. m)
Since it's out, you can see the current status at https://nova.iguw.tuwien.ac.at/

Thanks a lot. I just don't get where that »index.html« comes from. :/